# Adding roles with same names for different applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have just extended my IdentityRole like this:

```
public class AspApplicationRoles : IdentityRole
{
    public AspApplicationRoles() : base() { }
    public AspApplicationRoles(String Name) : base(Name) { }
    [Required]
    public String ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public AspNetApplications Application { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in order to add the same role names but have a different ApplicationId, I created a custom rolevalidator like this:

```
    public class ApplicationRoleValidator<TRole> : RoleValidator<TRole> where TRole : AspApplicationRoles
    {
        private RoleManager<TRole, string> Manager { get; set; }
        private AspApplicationRoles data = new AspApplicationRoles();
        private ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public ApplicationRoleValidator(RoleManager<TRole, string> manager) : base(manager)
        {
            Manager = manager;
        }

        public override async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(TRole Input)
        {
            data = dbContext.AspApplicationRoles.Where(ar => ar.ApplicationId == Input.ApplicationId && ar.Name == Input.Name).SingleOrDefault();
            if (data == null)
            {
                return IdentityResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return IdentityResult.Failed("Role already exists");
            }
        }
    }
```

I then had to change my applicationRoleManagers like this:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<AspApplicationRoles>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<AspApplicationRoles, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
        RoleValidator = new ApplicationRoleValidator<AspApplicationRoles>(this);
    }
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return manager;
    }
}
```

I have also removed the unique key on the database tables like this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        var role = modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .ToTable("AspNetRoles");
        role.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(
                new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex")
                { IsUnique = false }));
    }
```

However, I still can't have the same role names and I still get EntityValidationError "Role Manager already exists. I have tried to search for a solution but I can't seem to find it or see it.

EDIT:

This is how I call my new Role Validator

```
    public bool Save(SaveRolesDetailsViewModel Input)
    {
        bool result = false;
        AspApplicationRoles data = new AspApplicationRoles();
        var store = new ApplicationRoleStore(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager =new ApplicationRoleManager(store);
        try
        {
            var role = new AspApplicationRoles
            {
                Name = Input.RoleName,
                ApplicationId = Input.ApplicationId
            };
            var res = manager.RoleValidator.ValidateAsync(role);
            if (res.Result.Succeeded)
            {
                manager.Create(role);
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error(e, AspNetEventLogs.NotFound);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

EDIT 2:

Added the migration file that was generated after adding the OnModelCreating:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Name", name: "RoleNameIndex");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
        CreateIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "Name", unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");
    }
```

Comment: I am kind of confused about your classes, but 1) have you registered your classes 2) have you tried to debug?

Comment: Hi,  sorry I've edited my question to include how I used this new validator. I have tried to debug and the error I get everytime I enter a similar role name in a new application is that the name already exists

Comment: Ok, but does your code reach _your_ `ValidateAsync`?

Comment: Yeah it does. But it still gives me an error when it tries to create the rolename

Comment: Not relevant to your isduesue, but: as your ValidateAsync is async, why dont you use SingleOrDefaultAsync and some awaits?

Comment: No reason. I was following an example I found. Hoping to solve this one first before fixing up the rest of the items.

Comment: Ok. That means your code returns failure for a reason: your dbcontext returns an entity for that query. Are you sure your table does not contain any? Check everything!

Comment: what do you mean it's giving you an **error**? is it from your own `ValidateAsync` call: a `IdentityResult.Failed` result? or an actual Exception?

Comment: If you see my AspApplicationRoles Model, I extended IdentityRole and added an ApplicationId field. The main reason is so that I can have the role Manager for Application A and Manager for Application B as well. However right now I am getting the error when I call manager.create

Comment: @BrettCaswell ValidateAsync returns an IdentityResult.Success. Its when its time to create the role then it fails

Comment: I get an EntityValidationError "Role Manager already exists."

Comment: please update your question, add that information.. then go explicitly delete your obj folder contents in your application.. seems like a potential embedded schema issue here.

Comment: I updated the question and deleted my obj folder. Nothing changed.

Comment: are you using database first or code first generation?.. edmx file and T4 exist?

Comment: I'm using code first generation. Edmx file does not exist. I also added the migration that was generated after adding my OnModelCreating.